# How to preserve excel file's properties while uploading it to Google Sheets using gspread?

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas, google-drive-api, gspread

I want to upload an excel file to google sheets. Manually, I create a sheet using `sheets.new` url and then click on import, add the file from my local machine.

I want to automate this and so, wrote this code:

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import pandas as pd
import csv


# use creds to create a client to interact with the Google Drive API
scope = [
    'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
]
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
    'client_secret.json', scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)

path = 'Use_Case_test_cliDependency_2.xlsx'
file_id = client.create('Use_Case_test_cliDependency_2')
print('File ID is: {}'.format(file_id.id))
print('URL is: {}'.format(file_id.url))
content = pd.read_excel(path)
csv_path = path.split('.xlsx')[0]+'.csv'
content.to_csv(csv_path, index=False)
content = open(csv_path, 'r').read()
client.import_csv(file_id.id, content.encode('utf-8'))
print('Check client')
client.insert_permission(file_id.id, None, perm_type='anyone', role='reader')
```

This code runs successfully but all the arrows that I had in my excel sheet have vanished when running this code. Hence, how can I preserve the properties of my excel sheet just like I can when doing this manual?

By properties, I mean to include Bold cells, dark edges, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to upload a XLSX file to Google Drive as a Google Spreadsheet.

  - In your current situation, the content of XLSX file is retrieved with `pd.read_excel(path)`, and the data is put as the CSV data. In this case, all formats of XLSX are removed, while all formats are not removed when you manually convert the XLSX file to Google Spreadsheet.
  - You want to convert the XLSX file to Google Spreadsheet without removing the formats.
- You want to achieve this using gspread with python.
- You have already been able to get and put values for Google Spreadsheet and Google Drive using Sheets API and Drive API.

For this, how about this answer?

#### Modification points:

- In order to keep the formats of XLSX file, in this modification, the XLSX file is converted to Google Spreadsheet using Drive API, when the file is uploaded. By this, I think that the formats are kept when the XLSX is converted to Google Spreadsheet.

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import pandas as pd
import csv
import requests
import json

# use creds to create a client to interact with the Google Drive API
scope = [
    'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
]
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
    'client_secret.json', scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)
path = 'Use_Case_test_cliDependency_2.xlsx'
spreadsheet_name = 'Use_Case_test_cliDependency_2'

# Upload XLSX file by converting to Google Spreadsheet.
url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart'
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + client.auth.token}
metadata = {'name': spreadsheet_name, 'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'}
files = {
    'data': ('metadata', json.dumps(metadata), 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'),
    'file': open(path, 'rb')
}
res = requests.post(url, headers=headers, files=files)
obj = res.json()
fileId = obj['id']

# Create permission.
client.insert_permission(fileId, None, perm_type='anyone', role='reader')
```

- In this case, the XLSX file is uploaded to Google Drive by converting to Google Spreadsheet using the file create method in Drive API with `requests`.

#### Note:

- In this method, the maximum file size is 5 MB. Please be careful this.

#### References:

- [Files: create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create)
- [Upload files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads)